# Is SSH possible on remote networks?

Tags: iphone, ssh

I am trying to see if I can SSH to my iPhone using the 3G network. So, given my IP, I am trying to make contact through SSH, using the defined port (which is no longer 22, I changed it).

It all works fine on my private wifi network.
For some reason, it doesn't on 3G...

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Why the down and closing votes ?

Comment: this isn't the site you should be asking.  It's not a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unlikely that the IP you use points to your iPhone only. Seeing as how such a mobile server provider has to assign IP addresses to lots and lots of internet-enabled phones, I suspect they use [Network Address Translation (NAT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) or a similar technology to be able to assign one IP address to multiple devices. Seeing as NAT uses different ports to differentiate different devices, ssh is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are your mobile service provider will be blocking access. Don't forget that you do not have control over the router your phone connects too. At home you would open the port and forward traffic on that port to your computer from your router. On a mobile network, even if the port was open, it wouldn't know who to send the traffic too.